# Correctly returning results from multiple parse classes

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

Created a fiddle to show this issue http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/wj5vcd5m/12/

For example, at the moment you can add the user 'dave' multiple times. I'd like it to work that you can only add a user once.

More info

I want to be able to query the _User class and the FriendRequest class. Basically only returning a user that does not have a status of "Connected" from the FriendRequest class.

Using the below I get an error saying both queries must use the same class, whats the alternative to this or work around? Could I use `matchesKeyInQuery` instead?

```
var queryOne = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
            queryOne.equalTo("username", friendName); // find users that match

            var queryTwo = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
            queryTwo.notEqualTo("status", "Connected"); // find users that match

            var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryOne, queryTwo);

            mainQuery.find({
```

PARSE BACKEND.

So there can be multiple records in both the fromUser and toUser columns, but only one request to each user should be possible. For example

a3aePaphB4 can only have one record where a request is saved to netD5wqnRP

[image]

Comment: Yes, you should use `matchesKeyInQuery`.

Comment: @eth3lbert if you can provide an example I could accept as the answer

Comment: If you could provide the needed schema information, I could write an example.

Comment: @eth3lbert that would be fantasic! I've created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/wj5vcd5m/12/ I'm not understanding if the validation needs to happen in section 1 or 2. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 1:

Pairing user's `objectId` with `pic` so you could find the exact user you need in section 2.

e.g. `{userId: pic url, ...}`

call `Friendrequest` with userId as argument: `Friendrequest(userId)`

In section 2:

If could not get any results related to currentUser and the chosen user from query then make a friend request. Sample code:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.id = userId;
var query = new Parse.Query("FriendRequest");
query.containedIn("fromUser", [currentUser, user]);
query.containedIn("toUser", [currentUser, user]);
return query.first().then(function(record) {
  if (!record) {
    requestFriend.set("fromUser", currentUser);
    requestFriend.set("toUser", user);
    requestFriend.set("status", "Request sent")
    return requestFriend.save().then(function() {
      // request success
      alert('A friend request has been sent: ' + requestFriend.id);
      location.reload(true);
    });
  }
});
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Many thanks! Just so I fully understand is there anyway possible to update he fiddle? Just a full proof way to help me learn..

Comment: Also note, you could not have user with same username, so maybe you just get the first one with username or search with displayName or something else.

Comment: I think I follow roughly, are you able to update the fiddle to show what you mean?

Comment: Cheer, will accept the answer. Just one point, using your fiddle when trying to add a friend 'amy' or 'danny' it says the request is pending, but this is'nt the case there is'nt anything within the parse backend. Not sure if its a small glitch? - Or could be an issue with the way jfiddle works and caches the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65482/discussion-between-eth3lbert-and-dano007).